# Perl Hash Trouble

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

An easy one for a Perl guru...

I want a function that simply takes in an array of items (actually multiple arrays) and counts the number of times each item in the key section of a hash is there. However, I am really unsure of Perl hashes.

```
@array = qw/banana apple orange apple orange apple pear/
```

I read that you need to do arrays using code like this:

```
my %hash = (
    'banana' => 0,
    'orange' => 0,
    'apple' => 0
    #I intentionally left out pear... I only want the values in the array...
);
```

However, I am struggling getting a loop to work that can go through and add one to the value with a corresponding key equal to a value in the array for each item in the array.

```
foreach $fruit (@array) {
    if ($_ #is equal to a key in the hash) {
        #Add one to the corresponding value
    }
}
```

This has a few basic functions all wrapped up in one, so on behalf of all beginning Perl programmers, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exists`.

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exists.html

> Given an expression that specifies an element of a hash, returns true
>   if the specified element in the hash has ever been initialized, even
>   if the corresponding value is undefined.

```
foreach my $fruit (@array) {
    if (exists $hash{$fruit}) {
        $hash{$fruit}++;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need to check whether the hash element exists. Furthermore, as it stands your program will never modify the hash as *none* of the elements exist to start with.

Comment: My bad. I was under the impression he wanted to increment the values in the hash he defined.

Comment: Ah, I see. I think. You were assuming that the OP wanted only a subset of the words counted, as defined by the hash? In that case your code is fine.

Answer (score 6):

All you need is

```
my @array = qw/banana apple orange apple orange apple pear/;
my %counts;
++$counts{$_} for @array;
```

This results in a hash like

```
my %counts = ( apple => 3, banana => 1, orange => 2, pear => 1 )
```

The `for` loop can be written with block and a an explicit loop counter variable if you prefer, like this

```
for my $word (@array) {
  ++$counts{$word};
}
```

with exactly the same effect.

Comment: Is there a way to extend this to be able to work for multiple arrays?

Comment: @J.A.:  I'm not clear what you mean. If you want to accumulate the counts over multiple arrays then you can write `++$counts{$_} for @array1, @array2, @array3`

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have an array named `@array`. You'd access the 0th element of the array with `$array[0]`.

Hashes are similar. `%hash`'s banana element can be accessed with `$hash{'banana'}`.

Here's a pretty simple example. It makes use of the implicit variable `$_` and a little bit of string interpolation:

```
use strict;

my @array = qw/banana apple orange apple orange apple pear/;

my %hash;
$hash{$_} += 1 for @array;              #add one for each fruit in the list
print "$_: $hash{$_}\n" for keys %hash; #print our results
```

If needed, you can check if a particular hash key exists: `if (exists $hash{'banana'}) {...}`.

You'll eventually get to see something called a "hashref", which is not a hash but a *reference to* a hash. In that case, `$hashref` has `$hashref->{'banana'}`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to understand you here:

1. You have an array and a hash.
2. You want to count the items in the array and see how many time they occur
3. But, only if this item is in your hash.

Think of hashes as *keyed* arrays. Arrays have a position. You can talk about the 0th element, or the 5th element. There is only one 0th element and their is only one 5th element.

Let's look at a hash:

```
my %jobs;
$jobs{bob} = "banker";
$jobs{sue} = "banker";
$jobs{joe} = "plumber;
```

Just as we can talk about the element in the array in the 0th position, we can talk about the element with the of `bob`.  Just as there is only one element in the 0th position, there can only be one element with a key of `bob`.

Hashes provide a quick way to look up information. For example, I can quickly find out Sue's job:

```
print "Sue is a $jobs{sue}\n";
```

We have:

- An array filled with items.
- A hash with the items we want to count
- Another hash with the totals.

Here's the code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my @items       = qw(.....);   # Items we want to count
my %valid_items =   (....);    # The valid items we want

# Initializing the totals. Explained below...
my %totals;
map { $totals{$_} = 0; } keys %valid_items;

for my $item ( @items ) {
    if ( exists $valid_items{$item} ) {
        $totals{$item} += 1;  #Add one to the total number of items
    }
}

#
# Now print the totals
#
for my $item ( sort keys %totals ) {
    printf "%-10.10s  %4d\n", $item, $totals{$item};
}
```

The [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) command takes the *list of items* on the right side (in our case `keys %valid_items`), and loop through the entire list.

Thus:

```
map { $totals{$_} = 0; } keys %valid_items;
```

Is a short way of saying:

for ( keys %valid_items ) {
       $totals{$_} = 0;
    }

The other things I use are [keys](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html) which returns as an array (okay list) all of the keys of my hash. Thus, I get back `apple`, `banana`, and `oranges` when I say `keys %valid_items`.

The `[exists](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exists.html) is a test to see if a particular key is in my hash. The value of that key might be zero, a null string, or even an undefined value, but if the key is in my hash, the`exists` function will return a true value.

However, if we can use `exists` to see if a key is in my `%valid_items` hash, we could do the same with `%totals`. They have the same set of keys.

Instead or creating a `%valid_items` hash, I'm going to use a `@valid_items` array because arrays are easier to initialize than hashes. I just have to list the values. Instead of using `keys %valid_items` to get a list of the keys, I can use `@valid_items`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my @items = qw(banana apple orange apple orange apple pear);   # Items we want to count
my @valid_items = qw(banana apple orange);    # The valid items we want

my %totals;
map { $totals{$_} = 0; } @valid_items;

# Now %totals is storing our totals and is the list of valid items

for my $item ( @items ) {
    if ( exists $totals{$item} ) {
        $totals{$item} += 1;  #Add one to the total number of items
    }
}

#
# Now print the totals
#
for my $item ( sort keys %totals ) {
    printf "%-10.10s  %4d\n", $item, $totals{$item};
}
```

And this prints out:

```
apple          3
banana         1
orange         2
```

I like using [printf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html) for keeping tables nice and orderly.

Answer (score 1):

This will be easier to understand as I too started to write code just 2 months back.

```
use Data::Dumper;
use strict;
use warnings;
my @array = qw/banana apple orange apple orange apple pear/;

my %hashvar;
foreach my $element (@array) {
    #Check whether the element is already added into hash ; if yes increment; else add. 
    if (defined $hashvar{$element}) {  
        $hashvar{$element}++;
    }
    else {
        $hashvar{$element} = 1;

    }

}
print Dumper(\%hashvar);
```

Will print out the output as 
    $VAR1 = {
          'banana' => 1,
          'apple' => 3,
          'orange' => 2,
          'pear' => 1
        };
Cheers

Comment: There's no nee to check if it's defined first; just say `$hashvar{$element}++`; if it didn't exist before, it'll exist now, with a value of 1.